# How do I translate DOS assembly targeted for the small memory model to the large memory model?

Tags: memory, assembly, dos

I'm somewhat new to assembly language and wanted to understand how it works on an older system. I understand that the large memory model uses far pointers while the small memory model uses near pointers, and that the return address in the large model is 4 bytes instead of two, so the first parameter changes from `[bp+4]` to `[bp+6]`. However, in the process of adapting a graphics library from a small to a large model, there are other subtle things that I don't seem to understand. Running this code with a large memory model from C is supposed to clear the screen, but instead it hangs the system (it was assembled with TASM):

```
; void gr256cls( int color , int page );

COLOR   equ [bp+6]
GPAGE   equ [bp+8]

    .MODEL LARGE,C
.186
    public C    gr256cls
    .code
gr256cls    PROC
    push    bp
    mov bp,sp
    push    di
    pushf
    jmp skip_1
.386
    mov ax,0A800h
    mov es,ax
    mov ax,0E000h
    mov fs,ax
    CLD
    mov al,es:[bp+6]
    mov ah,al
    mov bx,ax
    shl eax,16
    mov ax,bx

    cmp word ptr GPAGE,0
    je  short cls0
    cmp word ptr GPAGE,2
    je  short cls0
    jmp short skip_0
cls0:
    mov bh,0
    mov bl,1
    call    grph_cls256
skip_0:
    cmp word ptr GPAGE,1
    je  short cls1
    cmp word ptr GPAGE,2
    je  short cls1
    jmp short skip_1
cls1:
    mov bh,8
    mov bl,9
    call    grph_cls256
skip_1:
.186
    popf
    pop di
    pop bp
    ret
.386
grph_cls256:
    mov fs:[0004h],bh
    mov fs:[0006h],bl
    mov cx,16384
    mov di,0
    rep stosd
    add word ptr fs:[0004h],2
    add word ptr fs:[0006h],2
    mov cx,16384
    mov di,0
    rep stosd
    add word ptr fs:[0004h],2
    add word ptr fs:[0006h],2
    mov cx,16384
    mov di,0
    rep stosd
    add word ptr fs:[0004h],2
    add word ptr fs:[0006h],2
    mov cx,14848    ;=8192+6656
    mov di,0
    rep stosd
    ;; Freezes here.
    ret
gr256cls    ENDP
    end
```

It hangs at the `ret` at the end of `grph_256cls`. In fact, even if I immediately `ret` from the beginning of the function it still hangs right after. Is there a comprehensive list of differences when coding assembly in the two modes, so I can more easily understand what's happening?

**EDIT**: To clarify, this is the original source. This is not generated output; it's intended to be assembled and linked into a library.

Comment: Note that in the large code model, function calls push a four byte return address on the stack. You might want to consider this in the definition of `COLOR` and `GPAGE`.

Comment: The parameters originally were `[bp+4]` and `[bp+6]`, with a two byte return address pushed on the stack, so I added two more bytes to each.

Comment: You need to show complete code with the all the steps your taking to build and run it so we can reproduce the problem. If necessary reduce the C code that calls this function to the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem. Make that the code in your post is exactly the same as what your using.

Comment: Just a guess: TASM may require  an explicit `retf`  in large model.

Comment: I replaced them all with `retf`s and it didn't make a difference. However I did find that if I skip `grph_cls256` entirely, there are no crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed `grph_256cls` to a procedure with `PROC FAR` and it now works without issue:

```
grph_cls256 PROC FAR
  ...
grph_cls256 ENDP
```

The issue had to do with how C expects functions to be called depending on the memory model. In the large memory model, all function calls are `far`. I hadn't labeled this assumption on the `grph_256cls` subroutine when trying to `call` it, so code that didn't push/pop the right values onto/off the stack was assembled instead.

Comment: It has nothing to do with what C expects because it's not C code that calls `grph_256cls`.

Comment: @RossRidge: Ah but it does. TASM is auto-adjusting for what C expects.

Comment: @Joshua No, it's not. That's the problem, if it were it would be doing so consistently.

Comment: @RossRidge: PROC vs PROC FAR is how you change your memory model. Until he changed that, his changes were oscillating between two non-working states that derive from mixing memory models.

Comment: @Joshua No, that's not the change he made.